# VBA Excel 2013 Finding specific string length and adding a value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro to find if a cell has 5 numeric values and if it does, I need to add a 0 at the end.

My macro already has some steps in it.

For example

1. Cell `BZ2` = 9.48E+00
2. My macro finds the decimal point and replaces it with `94811E-5`
3. I need to add a Zero in this case, because there are 5 numeric values, AND only when the last three characters are `E-5`.

Expected result is `948110E-5`.

I am using a number stored as text.

Can anyone help me out?

```
Sub TextFormat()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim d As Range

    For Each c In Sheets("order_export").Range("F2:F10000").Cells
        If StrComp(Right(c.Value, 1), "R", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            c.Offset(0, -1).Value = c.Offset(0, -1).Value & "R"
            c.Value = Left(c.Value, Len(c.Value) - 1)
        End If
    Next c

    For Each d In Sheets("order_export").Range("BZ2:BZ10000").Cells
        If InStr(1, d.Value, ".", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            d.NumberFormat = "@"
            d.Value = Replace(d.Value, ".", "")
            d.Value = d.Value & "E-5"
        End If
    Next d
End Sub
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: I thought that I would need to add the next step after my last if?

Answer (score 1):

using this conditional

```
 if isNumeric(left(text,5)) AND right(text,3) = "E-5" then
     'add zero
     text = left(text,5) & "0" & right(text, len(text) - 5)
 end if
```

will add the 0 after the first 5 if the first 5 characters are numeric and the last 3 are e-5. the `left` function takes the first 5 characters. the `isNumeric` checks if they are numeric. and then the rest, takes the first 5 characters, puts a 0, and then the `right` takes all characters starting from the right going up till length - 5 (we already have the first 5 characters)

### edit

as pointed out, if there is already a 0, like 123450E-5 then an extra would be added.

add `ANd len(text) = 8` so that it only adds the 0 if there are 8 characters.

Comment: not fail,just add an extra 0 haha could add `if len(text) = 8` also. like ...`and len(text = 8)` cuz really `Len(Left(text, Len(text) - 3)) = 5` is fancy for length = 8

Answer (score 0):

Excel doesn't [short circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) so for coding efficiency it is better to break an `AND` into `IF's` with the most likely errors first, then the breaches

Also never using the variant functions `Left` and `Right` use string functions `Left$` and `Right$` instead

This [link](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/stringopt.html#variant) is an excellent resource re coding optimisation.

Re-cutting the earlier answers would be something like this:

```
c = "94811E-5"

If Len(c) = 8 Then
    If IsNumeric(Left$(c, 5)) Then
            If Right$(c, 3) = "E-5" Then c = Left$(c, Len(c) - 3) & "0" & Right$(c, 3)
    End If
End If

MsgBox c
```